# Facebook link_stat Incorrect Unique URL Stat

Tags: facebook

I'm using this FQL to get the number of likes of every article in my app.

SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://www.example.com/some/dir/slug"

However, I've been noticing that the number and the like button doesn't seem to take the slug into factor. So when I'm debugging it in Graph API Explorer, the stat for http://www.example.com/some/dir/slug and http://www.example.com/some/dir is the same.

Is this FB bug?

Thanks

Comment: What does the `og:url` meta tag for these article pages look like?

Comment: http://www.example.com/some/dir/ , as this app resides in the subdirectory of the main site -- oh i see. Then the `og:url` has to be the url with slug?

Comment: Well that means you are telling Facebook that all those pages should be treated as the same URL `http://www.example.com/some/dir/`, so all likes get counted for that very URL.

Comment: So the `og:url` should be the current URL right? Thanks. Please answer it so I can mark your answer as the correct one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `og:url` meta tag has to contain the individual URL for each article - otherwise, if it is the same URL value for all articles, Facebook will count all likes for that very URL.

Comment: I just change the `og:url` to be the current URL, however the like_count is still the same as before (the one when `og:url` is still `http://www.example.com/some/dir`). Is this FB cache? If it is, how long does it last?

Comment: All your likes up to that point will of course still count for the old og:url. You have to get new likes for your articles now that you fixed them to show the right URL value.